# Sci-Fi Book Artificial Intelligence starts out as a simulated child on a desktop computer

Tags: story-identification, artificial-intelligence, audio-book

I'm looking for a book I read in the last 3-4 years and I can remember some basic plot points but nothing specific.
It is about an Artificial intelligence that becomes kinda evil (as they tend to do).

- The AI starts off with the mind of a small child and he has two researchers that are basically his "babysitters". There's also some sort of department head who is kind of the AI's mother and she's not around much and doesn't really believe in the project.
- At some point the AI connects to the internet somehow and that's how the singularity moment comes about.
- I should also mention that I don't believe the AI was ever in a human form. He definitely started out in a normal desktop computer that wasn't even fancy. There was this whole thing about it just re-creating the top layers of the mind because the rest was too much hard work(computing).
- It's available in audiobook form and I think it was definitely read by a woman.

I believe it's not a very old book, written in the last 10 years probably and I think (although I'm far from certain) that it's written by a woman.

Comment: Was one of the characters a blind girl?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: "As they tend to do" your speciesist statement offends me sir/madam/androgyne , with that being said can you remember in what way its actions could be perceived as evil.

Comment: Reddit saved me on this one :P
The book is Run Program by Scott Meyer

Comment: @Xovius you can post an answer to your own question to show the book has been identified. Future visitors to the site might find that helpful if they're interested in the book.

Answer (score 2):

Per the OP's comment above, this is Scott Meyer's *[Run Program](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2189902)*, published 2017. From the [official summary](http://www.scottmeyer.rocks/run-program/):

> What’s worse than a child with a magnifying glass, a garden full of
> ants, and a brilliant mind full of mischief?
>
> Try **Al, a well-meaning but impish artificial intelligence with the
> mind of a six-year-old** and a penchant for tantrums. Hope Takeda, a lab
> assistant charged with educating and socializing Al, soon discovers
> that day care is a lot more difficult when your kid is an evolving and
> easily frightened A.I.
>
> **When Al manages to access the Internet and escape the lab days before
> his official unveiling**, Hope and her team embark on a mission to
> contain him—before he causes any real trouble.
>
> Soon the NSA is on Al’s back, the US Army is fighting a brigade of
> mass-produced robots, and a wannabe cyberterrorist is looking to
> silence Al permanently. After months spent “raising” Al, Hope knows
> she’s running out of time—and she’s not sure she’ll be able to protect
> him. Will she manage to control the unruly A.I. and quell a global
> crisis, or will Al outsmart them once and for all?